# Vite proxy issue typescript react

Tags: typescript, proxy, vite

Has anyone got this proxy works? i have server serving data on / at localhost:3000 and to avoid cors when reaching /api I'm trying to setup proxy as below

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),

      }
    }
  }
})
```

But when I run npm run dev (it just run vite - "dev": "vite") and trying to make a GET request http://127.0.0.1:5173/api I always get

```
9:16:44 AM [vite] http proxy error at :
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16)
```

When I setup proxy in separated script using http-proxy directly it works great. Is there any issue in with my config, vite or what?? Tested with node 21.5 and 18.19

To catch details of error have added

```
configure: (proxy, options) => {
    proxy.on('error', (err, _req, _res) => {
                console.log('proxy error', err);
              });
```

and this is what error contains

```
proxy error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3000
}
```

I'd like to have this return the same as "data server endpoint".